# How can I change opacity and color of UITableViewCell when i use moveRow(at:,to:)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4

Here is my code. My swift version is 4.

```swift
tableview.beginUpdates() 
tableview.moveRow(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0), to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 2))
tableview.endUpdates()
```

There is the problem changing section of tableview. Because each section has other opacity and color, I want the opacity and color to change as soon as using moveRow(at:,to:).

But I can't find how do i. Please Help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a custom UITableViewCell class. You could write a function inside that class that manipulate the cells appearance. Let's say you have a bunch of outlets inside that class, you can make a function that changes those view elements. The alpha and the color etc.

Call this function on the cell inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCellClass
cell.apperanceFunction(alpha: Double, background: UIColor)
```

at the specific section inside the if or switch I must assume you have. When you move the cell to that section cellForRowAtIndexPath should be called again and the function should be called on that specific cell. If it does not, you can always manually find that cell using the cellForRow(at: indexPath) function in your ViewController and call that function specifically.

Hope this makes sense... But It's a bit hard when this is the only code you provide.

Comment: Thanks for answering. you mean I must call cellForRowAtIndexPath whenever I move the cell using moveRow(at:,to:), right? If I understand correctly, I want to know how can I call cellForRowAtIndexPath. As I know, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called when TableView is created. But I don't know how can I call that manually. Now, I'm using reloadSections. I'm not sure this is the right way.

Comment: I thought that cellForRowAtIndexPath would get called automatically, but a bit of research tells me it don't ;) - So the approach you have with the reload section is what you want to do. - However, if you don't need to update the entire section you could also just use reloadRows(at:with:) and update that specific row. That should also call cellForRowAtIndexPath for that that specific row only.

Comment: Otherwise what I meant is if you have a function inside your cell class, you can always try and find the cell with the "function" cellForRowAtIndexPath. and then call that function. Example:
let cellToFind = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath) as? CustomCellClass and then call that specific function like:
cellToFind.apperanceFunction()

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow

But the above solution with reloadRows or reloadSections seems more clean. Weird that it does not automatically do it. If you remove and insert the row instead, it will ;)